# Question mark on finder's side bar -- could it be malware?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, malware

[image]

When I click on this question mark finder tells me it can't open it because the original item couldn't be found. A week ago I downloaded a file that I suspect could have been malware. Could a malware manifest this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. A question mark is the usual symbol for a link to a file that no longer exists or cannot be found.

Malware is designed to go unnoticed.